# connect and run adb commands on 25 devices via TCP WiFi without ever connecting any USB

Tags: tcp, adb

i am trying to send adb commands to over 25 Android devices using TCP- Through my WiFi connection: May i know how i can skip connecting each or any of this devices through USB first before running the adb commands?

Comment: The script i have requires me to connect each device via USB at a time, yet i need my script to run if possible on all devices at ago, WITHOUT being asked to manually connect to USB at any Time..

Answer (score 0):

In the first time that you connect to the device - you must connect with a usb cable and write these adb commands:

```
adb tcpip xxxx
adb connect yy.yy.yy.yy:xxxx
```

where the xxxx - is 4 digits port and the yy.yy.yy.yy is the device ip address

Then, every time you want to connect - you should just write again this code - and you don't need to connect the device using USB cable!

Comment: Thank you for that Answer; my concern is, do i have to connect each of the 25 devices at least once with  the USB?, is there anyway of skipping this processes?

Comment: Do you want to connect just one device by USB? I don't think that you have a way to do it. I think you must connect **each** device one time by USB - and then you can connect all of them by `adb` commands without USB connections.